# How to replace `eval` when assigning variables in Bash

Tags: bash, function, eval

I have a function `myFunction()` that shall take an integer variable from outside, print it and then increment it.

This works:

`myFunction`:

```sh
myFunction() {
    local var="${1}"
    eval "printf '%s\n' \$$var"
    eval "$var=$(($var+1))"
}
```

But, I don't want to use `eval` in this as a user of this function might enter a wrong variable name that might then be executed. I would like to use something like `printf -v` as it would make the usage safer.

How can I do this?

Comment: The linked duplicate's answers are overkill for this case. Just use `myFunction() { printf '%s\n' "${!1}"; (($1++)); }` -- Indirect variable reference + the fact that `$` refs are expanded first in arithmetic expressions takes care of it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks a lot! This works just fine! Could you post it as an answer, I would like to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

You can (only?) do this without eval if you are happy enumerating all possible variable names.

```sh
myFunction () {
  case $1 in
  (frobme)    printf '%s\n' $frobme; : $((++frobme));;
  (zapme)     printf '%s\n' $zapme;  : $((++zapme));;
  (*)         printf 'invalid name: %s\n' "$1" >&2;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know the variable names in advance.